# Перетаскивание изображения из PictureBox в другой PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Имеется несколько PictureBox В которые юзер загружает нужные картинки. Нужно что бы он мог менять их местами перетаскиванием. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: В гугле или в английской версии stackoverflow нужно написать:
"windows form drag and drop picturebox" (без кавычек). Высока вероятность наткнуться на пример: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51091782/3786094 и оттуда же ссылка на гитхаб: https://github.com/javon27/PictureBox_DragDrop_Example. Скачал код, проверил, работает как нужно.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задаём всем пикчабоксам свойство:

```
pictureBox1.AllowDrop = true;
```

Это свойство зачем-то скрыто у этого контрола, но оно есть.

Подписываем все пикчабоксы на события:

```
private void PictureBox_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(PictureBox)))
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }
}

private void PictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var pictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;
    pictureBox.DoDragDrop(pictureBox, DragDropEffects.Move);
}

private void PictureBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var sourcePictureBox = e.Data.GetData(typeof(PictureBox)) as PictureBox;
    var targetPictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;

    var tempImage = sourcePictureBox.Image;
    sourcePictureBox.Image = targetPictureBox.Image;
    targetPictureBox.Image = tempImage;
}
```

Comment: Не учите людей плохому) `The PictureBox control is not designed to allow drag and drop procedures`!

Comment: Если свойство скрыто, то скрыто не просто так. Если даже в рамках текущего примера все вроде бы работает как надо, то никто не гарантирует, что так будет продолжаться и далее

Comment: Так что я бы советовал заменить `PictureBox` на ту же панельку (`Panel`) и двигать ее, рисуя на ней то, что душе угодно